# Regex matching filenames

Tags: regex, bash

I Know this will sound silly to some of you but I am not good with regex resolutions. I came across the following expressions in a function someone else has written and can't figure out what he/she was doing.

REGEX 1

```
[ ! -d ${2%/*}/ ]
```

REGEX 2

```
cmp -s $2 ${2##*/}
```

as you can guess, these  regex evaluations are being used in a script, doing file updating and moving them around. I was wondering the meaning of

```
${2%/*}/
```

and

```
${2##*/}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take an example to understand better:

```
s='abc/def/foo'
echo "${s%/*}/"
abc/def/

echo "${s##*/}"
foo
```

1. First expression is discarding text after last `/` in the input.
2. Second expression is discarding all the text before last `/` in the input.

You can see more details in `man bash`:

- `##*/` is used to match longest string before `/` from start of input string.
- `%/*` is used to match text after `/` from end of input.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like this question should be tagged as `bash` instead of `regex` since the patterns in the question actually contain **wildcard characters**.